# Debugging MVC Web Page - Failed to load resource: ... 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis-express, internal-server-error

VS 2017 .NET 4.7

I am developing an `MVC` web site (not MVC Core).
From within `Visual Studio 2017`, I hit the play button and it starts up Chrome and displays the home page, nothing special there.  However, today the web page is being displayed with **no styling**.
I looked in the Chrome console window and discovered that none of the css/js/ico files were being loaded.
An example message (same for all) is:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)  bootstrap.js

So far I've tried:

1. Falling back to the previous weeks version of the code (problem
   still exists)
2. Creating a new skeleton MVC site from scratch (that works fine)
3. Checked another much larger project (that works fine)

Same issue if I load the site in Edge.

I am using IIS Express on an Hyper-V virtual machine (if that matters)

Anybody have any ideas what may have caused this issue to arise?

Comment: Update:  In the same solution I also have a Web API.  If I go to that projects home page, the styling works fine.  It does not exhibit the same problem.

Comment: Also tried deleting the projects 'bin' folder and rebuilding - same issue.

Comment: It was caused by me adding these lines into the Web.Config file
<staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-font-woff2" />
    </staticContent>

Comment: Could you answer your own question with this solution? this worked for me as well!